# xcode6.0.1 not able to start my app on Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I updated xcode to version 6.0.1, and tried to run my app on device, but it did not work, where show me the message (Build succeeded) , and then closing xcode!

I updated the device to ios 8, and changed the certificates, but the problem still exists.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I happened the same to me. I solved it by deleting xcode and re-installing it again.